# php pdo fill in a table with array from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

im trying to insert data from MySQL into a table however I can't seem to get the loop working correcty :(

The select statement is correct, I just cant get it to echo the data out correctly.

Any idea?

Edited code is below which I fixed :)

There error is

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in /home/4507408/public_html/review.php on line 67
```

.

```
<?php

$sql  = "SELECT u.userID, p.productID, p.name, c.categoryname, r.reviewID, r.reviewTime, r.reviewData, u.firstname FROM review r INNER JOIN product p on p.productID = r.productID INNER JOIN user u on u.userID = r.userID INNER JOIN category c on c.categoryID = p.categoryID ORDER BY $sortby ASC;";

$query = $DBH->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$data = $query->fetchALL();
$originalDate = $row['reviewTime'];
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
while($row = $data->(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))                     
{

?>

<table class="rev">

<tr>
<th><a href="review.php?sort=name">Product Name:</a></th>
<th><a href="review.php?sort=categoryname">Category</a></th>
<th><a href="review.php?sort=reviewID">ID</a></th>
<th><a href="review.php?sort=reviewTime">Date</a></th>
<th><a href="review.php?sort=reviewData">Review</a></th>
<th><a href="review.php?sort=firstname">Reviewer's Name</a></th>
</tr>


<td><a href="viewproduct.php?productID=<?=$row['productID']?>"><?=$name?></a></td>
<td><?=$row['categoryname']?></td>
<td><?=$row['reviewID']?></td>
<td><?=$newDate?></td>
<td><?=$row['reviewData']?></td>
<td><?=$row['firstname']?></td>
</tr>

<?      } ?>
```

CORRECT CODE:

```
                                                <?php

                                                $sql  = "SELECT u.userID, p.productID, p.name, c.categoryname, r.reviewID, r.reviewTime, r.reviewData, u.firstname FROM review r INNER JOIN product p on p.productID = r.productID INNER JOIN user u on u.userID = r.userID INNER JOIN category c on c.categoryID = p.categoryID ORDER BY $sortby ASC;";

                                                $query = $DBH->prepare($sql);
                                                $query->execute();
                                                $data = $query->fetchALL();

                                                ?>

                                    <table class="rev">

                                                <tr>
                                                <th><a href="review.php?sort=name">Product Name:</a></th>
                                                <th><a href="review.php?sort=categoryname">Category</a></th>
                                                <th><a href="review.php?sort=reviewID">ID</a></th>
                                                <th><a href="review.php?sort=reviewTime">Date</a></th>
                                                <th><a href="review.php?sort=reviewData">Review</a></th>
                                                <th><a href="review.php?sort=firstname">Reviewer's Name</a></th>
                                                </tr>

                                                <? foreach ($data as $row): ?>
                                                <?
                                                $originalDate = $row['reviewTime'];
                                                $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
                                                ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><a href="viewproduct.php?productID=<?=$row['productID']?>"><?=$row['productID']?></a></td>
                                                    <td><?=$row['categoryname']?></a></td>
                                                    <td><?=$row['reviewID']?></a></td>
                                                    <td><?=$newDate?></a></td>
                                                    <td><?=$row['reviewData']?></a></td>
                                                    <td><?=$row['firstname']?></a></td>
                                                </tr>


                                                <? endforeach?>


                                        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line doesn't make any sense:

```
while($row = $data->(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

I think what you need ([based on the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)) is

```
foreach ($data as $row)
```

since `fetchAll` returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

it should be,

```
 $data = $query->fetchALL();
 foreach($data as $row)
```

instead of

```
  while($row = $data->(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

Also,

```
<?php  } ?>
```

not until you have not configure the shortag

```
<?   } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks I have solved it now and updated the question with correct code.

Comment: In the process of transferring over to PDO

Answer (score 0):

@jon is correct you need a foreach loop and you need to place PDO::FETCH_ASSOC into $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)